# Endpoints Proto Datastore custom property names

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

Is there a way to create a subclass of EndpointsModel with properties that define a custom name? i.e:

```
    class ProfilesApi(remote.Service):
    @Profile.method(name='user', path='user')
      def details(self, profile):
        return profile

    class Profile(EndpointsModel):
      user_id = ndb.StringProperty('uid')
```

Getting the following error:

```
INFO     2014-09-30 15:54:10,066 module.py:652] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 200 3922
ERROR    2014-09-30 15:54:10,071 service.py:191] Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: AttributeError ('Profile' object has no attribute 'uid')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py", line 181, in protorpc_service_app
    response = method(instance, request)
  File ".../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_config.py", line 1329, in invoke_remote
    return remote_method(service_instance, request)
  File ".../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/remote.py", line 412, in invoke_remote_method
    response = method(service_instance, request)
  File ".../default/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py", line 1327, in EntityToRequestMethod
    response = response.ToMessage(fields=response_fields)
  File ".../default/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py", line 1080, in ToMessage
    value = getattr(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'uid'
INFO     2014-09-30 15:54:10,076 module.py:652] default: "POST /_ah/spi/ProfilesApi.details HTTP/1.1" 500 512
INFO     2014-09-30 15:54:10,077 module.py:652] default: "POST /_ah/api/my_project/v2/user HTTP/1.1" 503 196
```

The issue seems to be in endpoints_proto_datastore, right? I guess there is an specific way to do this. I just haven't found any sample or documentation about it.

Comment: The custom name is only used for storage in datastore, and it seems also in the API representation. In your own code you will still have to use the actual property name. I just tested this with a simple sample and the API seems to work okay with custom names. Can you maybe add the code that throws the error?

Comment: @Scarygami I just edited the question to include the error stack trace. I'm doing a simple post to the 'user' api. Tried doing with "userId": "value", and "uid": "value", both fail with the same error. Thanks for your time! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Looking at the line numbers/code in the stack trace, it seems you are not using the newest version of the endpoints_proto_datastore library. Can you update and try again? I think this might have been fixed since it works without problems in my sample.

Comment: @Scarygami you're right. I was using an old version. The link to the zip file in the github readme file is not the latest version. I just pulled it form the repo and worked fine. Thanks again!

Comment: @Scarygami it was reported back in February, but hasn't been fixed yet. Thanks a lot for your time! https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/issues/78